# How to get one item from option list

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm trying to get one item from my database from an ejs option list.

here my code

```
<form action="/chords/id" method='POST'>
    <select name="root" id="root">
        <%chords.forEach(function(chord){%>
            <option value="<%=chord.id%>"><%=chord.root%></option>
       <% }) %>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <%chords.forEach(function(chord){%>
            <option value=""><%=chord.type%></option>
       <% }) %>
    </select>
    <select name="extension" id="extension">
        <%chords.forEach(function(chord){%>
            <option value=""><%=chord.extension%></option>
       <% }) %>
    </select>


    <input type="submit" value='SUBMIT'>

</form>
```

My database has 4 keys : root, type, extension and note. My idea is I select root, type and extension from the option list, then this should return me the note of the chord and print the chord.note on the page. How can i do this ? What should i pass in the form action for the route ? Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about ejs but in JavaScript we cant do something like this upon submit event:

```
const select = event.target.elements['select']
const optionValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value

console.info('Value:', optionValue)
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the chord.id on the `option` value for extension and type.

[Check in the example](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/BgrbXV)